# Unable to connect to "https" site using VUGen for recording

Tags: loadrunner

I am trying to connect to a https website in order to record scripts using VUGen. I have configured recording options with correct certificate which is of format .jks and the right password. But, VUGen still complaints that 
"X509 Certificate & key combination is either invalid or doesn't exist"
Has anyone faced a similar issue? if so, could you pease help me fix this one ?

Comment: Are you sure this is an HTTPS site that requires client certificate?